# selecting and filtering cloudflare pagerules with jq

Tags: select, filter, jq, cloudflare

I was trying to work out the best way to filter out some pagerules data from Cloudflare, and while I've got a solution I'm looking at how ugly it is and thinking "there has to be a simpler way to do this."

I'm specifically asking about a better way to achieve the following goal using jq.  I understand there are programming libraries I could use to accomplish the same, but the point of this question is to get a better understanding of how jq is intended to work.

Say I've got a long list of CloudFlare pagerules records, here are a few  entries as a minimal example:

```
{
  "example.org": [
    {
      "id": "341",
      "targets": [
        {
          "target": "url",
          "constraint": {
            "operator": "matches",
            "value": "http://ng.example.org/*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "actions": [
        {
          "id": "always_use_https"
        }
      ],
      "priority": 12,
      "status": "active",
      "created_on": "2017-11-29T18:07:36.000000Z",
      "modified_on": "2020-09-02T16:09:03.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "406",
      "targets": [
        {
          "target": "url",
          "constraint": {
            "operator": "matches",
            "value": "http://nz.example.org/*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "actions": [
        {
          "id": "always_use_https"
        }
      ],
      "priority": 9,
      "status": "active",
      "created_on": "2017-11-29T18:07:55.000000Z",
      "modified_on": "2020-09-02T16:09:03.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "427",
      "targets": [
        {
          "target": "url",
          "constraint": {
            "operator": "matches",
            "value": "nz.example.org/*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "actions": [
        {
          "id": "ssl",
          "value": "flexible"
        }
      ],
      "priority": 8,
      "status": "active",
      "created_on": "2017-11-29T18:08:00.000000Z",
      "modified_on": "2020-09-02T16:09:03.000000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is extract the urls nested in the constraint.value fields for the always_use_https actions.  The goal is to extract the values and return them as a json array. What I came up with is this:

```
jq '[                                       
        [
                [
                        [
                                .[] | .[] | select(.actions[].id | contains("always_use_https"))
                        ] | .[].targets[] | select(.target | contains("url"))
                ] | .[] | .constraint | select(.operator | contains("matches"))
        ] | .[].value 
]'
```

Against our example this produces:

```
[
  "http://ng.example.org/*",
  "http://nz.example.org/*"
]
```

Is there a more succinct way to achieve this in jq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the expected output in accordance with the criteria as I understand them:

```
jq '.["example.org"]
    | map(select( any(.actions[]; .id == "always_use_https"))
          | .targets[]
          | select(.target == "url")
          | .constraint.value )
' cloudfare.json
```

Comment: Thank you, the `map()` and `any()` operators were very useful to learn about.
I did make one additional change to your improvement, which was to change `.constraint.value` to `.constraint | select( .operator == "matches" ) | .value`